# Scaling node.js express app using docker swarm

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am trying to scale my express server that runs in a docker swarm.
when run my stack and there are 2 replicas of the express server on the same machine everything works fine, but as soon as i add another server to the swarm and my express app runs a container on each server then the issue begins.

The issue that I experience is:

1. POST REQUEST FROM UI
2. OPTIONS preflight is performed - gets 204 status code from my backend
3. the request hangs and the POST is not being sent.

What I have tried:

1. tried to see if it is something that has to do with CORS, but i don't think so because i have managed to make it work on one server which is also in a different origin from the frontend.
2. tried running the express application only on the worker node (the new node i added to the cluster), and it managed to get the post request to it.
3. tried running the application on the master node only - it worked.

both servers are behind a load balancer i created (don't know if that is an issue or not when it comes to express)
both servers run on EC2 instances on aws
base image - node:8-alpine
express version :     "express": "^4.17.1",

Comment: What do you mean both servers have the same DNS? Are you using DNS load balancing?

Comment: @slebetman, there is an A record for each of the ips - for instance
A --> smart.mydomain.com --> ip1
A --> smart.mydomain.com --> ip2

Comment: For the same domain name?

Comment: @slebetman, yes.
is this the problem ?

Comment: because i have read that there can be 2 A record for the same subdomain with different ips @slebetman

Comment: That normally won't work with regular DNS servers. To do that you need to use a DNS load balancer. Some DNS hosting services like Cloudflare provides DNS load balancing service (also called round-robin-DNS). They use a custom or modified DNS server to do this. DNS **must** always resolve only to a **single** IP address but DNS load balancer will either take turn which IP address it replies (round-robin) or reply the single IP address randomly. That's what the "A" means in A records - AUTHORITATIVE - it means this ONE SINGLE IP ADDRESS is for sure the IP address (authoritative) for this domain

Comment: Since you are using a load balancer your DNS allocation is wrong anyway. It should be smart.mydomain.com --> HTTP load balancer, ip1 not assigned to anything, ip2 not assigned to anything

Comment: @slebetman, sorry for me not being percise.
i am using cloudflare's load-balancer and this is what i meant :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208058/discussion-between-slebetman-and-eitank).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while i found out that the issue was that i didn't run swarm on the public IP of both of the ec2 instances.

make sure that when you initialise swarm that you listen on the public ip of the server.

`docker swarm init --advertise-addr  <public ip>`

same thing for joining the swarm.